# Read one value from the last row of a SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have a database with some columns and one of that is called `ID` (datatype = `int`).
I need to know the value of the `ID` of the last row (for last row I mean the last created).

I tried this, but it gives a runtime error:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Customer)";
SqlCeCommand comSelect = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
SqlCeDataReader rdr = comSelect.ExecuteReader();
int ID = rdr.GetInt32(6);
```

(`GetInt32(6)` because `ID` is the 6th column)

Thanks all, and sorry for my english.

P.S.

Customer is my table and ID are set in ascending order. The first row created has `ID = 0` the second `ID = 1` etc.

I need to know the last id because when I create a new customer I want to set his `ID` to previous customer `ID+1`

Errors:

> Exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll unhandled in user code

Comment: And *which* runtime error do you get?

Comment: Exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: What's the message in the exception?

Comment: post the message in exception and stacktrace

Comment: Why not just use auto increment?

Comment: If you just need the last id, why don't simply run the query = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Customer" ?

Comment: I hope you need to refer `GetInt32(5)` if it is 6th column since column starts with `0` based index

Comment: Your strategy would be thread unsafe, the auto increment is the way to go.

Comment: GetInt32(6) is right it is the 7th columns, sorry :P

Comment: How can i run that query and get the int ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the fact that probably there is no problem with concurrency you could simply get the last ID with an [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.executescalar%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) call

```
string query ="SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Customer";
SqlCeCommand comSelect = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
int ID = (int)comSelect.ExecuteScalar();
```

ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row in the result set.
The query `SELECT MAX(ID)` returns just one row with only one column. So ExecuteScalar fits perfectly in this scenario. No need to use an ExecuteReader

However, the correct way to handle your autoincrement scenario is to use [an IDENTITY column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174639.aspx) that will automatically set the next value for you when you insert a new record.
In  this situation you have marked the ID column with the IDENTITY property to TRUE and then you insert your data in the table Customer without passing any value for the ID column. After the insert you retrieve immediately the value assigned by the database to your ID column

Pseudocode

```
string query ="INSERT INTO Customers (Name, Address, .....) VALUES (.....)";
SqlCeCommand comInsert = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
comInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
query ="SELECT @@IDENTITY";
SqlCeCommand comSelect = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
int ID = (int)comSelect.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! this worked perfectly ! Can you tell me how to use this autoincrement ? it seems a really better solution :)

Comment: You set the IDENTITY property to your column and let the database calculate the next number when you insert the record. Remember that you don't need anymore to pass a value for this field. After the insert you could retrieve the last value inserted using the query SELECT @@IDENTITY

Comment: Thanks you a lot ! i'm a newbie to sql :)

Comment: Glad to be of help, and don't worry for the newbie thing. At the beggining we were all beginners. See you again on SO

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the `Id` and you may have other users its better to save the new data and get the I'd, or whole new object, returned from the db by the code saving the row. If you try and keep track of `user ids` other users could add new items and mess things up.

If you have to get last I'd from the db then you can use `@inserted` in your sql to get the last row added.